# Overwrote built in function - Standard deviation

Tags: matlab, standard-deviation

I want to have a std.m file for the standard deviation. It is in data fun toolbox, but, by mistake, I changed the code and the `std` command is not working anymore. How can I run the original `std` (standard deviation) command?

Comment: `function y = std(varargin) ; y = sqrt(var(varargin{:}));` This is the content of the `std.m` function. Fix it, then immediately set all your Matlab built-in files to **read-only**

Comment: Hey Hoki, thanks for your help. Sure, i will change my built infiles to read only :D

Comment: @Hoki post as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking all the comments out, the function `std.m` is actually extremely simple:

```
function y = std(varargin)
    y = sqrt(var(varargin{:}));
```

This is the definition of the `standard deviation`: the square root of the `Variance`.

---

- Set built-in functions to **Read-Only**

Now don't go breaking the `var.m` file because it is more complex and I wonder if there would be copyright issue to display the listing here.

To avoid the problem of breaking built-in files, it is advisable to set all your Matlab toolbox files as ***Read Only***. I remember old Matlab installer giving the option to do that at install time. I don't know if the installer still offers the option, but if not it is extremely easy to do it manually (on *Windows*, just select your folders, right-click `Properties`, tick *read only* and accept to propagate the property to all subfolders and files).

---

- **Overloading**

Once this is done, your built-in files are safe. You can still modify the default behavior of a built-in function by *overloading* it. This consist in writing a function with the same name and arrange for it to be called before the default function (your overload function becomes the default one).

This [article](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/overloading-functions-for-your-class.html) explain how to overload user functions.

Matlab does not recommend to directly overload the built-in functions (rather call it another name like `mySTD.m` for example), but if you insist it is perfectly feasible and still a much better option than *modifying* the built-in function... *at least the original function is still intact somewhere*.